# How to get data from input field using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, input, textfield

How to get data from an HTML text field and use it in RoR?

For example, let's say I enter a word in the text field and RoR prints how many characters are in said word.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do that is using the JAVASCRIPT but you insist for ROR use observe_field

```
<%= text_field  :users, :word, :value=>'',  :autocomplete=>'off' %><br>
<span id="word_message" style="color :red; font-size: 9px;"></span>
<%= observe_field  :users_word,  :url => {  :action =>  :word_length,  :id=>1 },
               :on=>"blur",
               :frequency => 0.25,
               :with => "'word='+value" %>
```

In Controller

```
def word_length
  word = params[:word]
  render :update do |page|
    page.replace_html  'word_message', "#{word.length} characters"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
However I get: undefined method `observe_field' for #<#<Class:0x3eeddf0>:0x3eec950>

Rails 3.0.7
Ruby 1.9.2